# Can I pay tips with credit card in Israel (just like in US)

Tags: israel, tipping, tel-aviv

I've asked a couple of times in restraunts but I guess I failed to explain what I actually want after all. So, my question is - can I ask to include tips to the bill in Israel or should I instead always carry some cash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On many places they will agree to take the tip from your card and some places will not agree
You would have to ask
Try using google translator
Or show them the following sentence in Hebrew

**האם אני יכול לשלם את הטיפ באשראי?**
May I pay the tip with credit [card]?

Enjoy your stay

Answer (score 7):

From the Haaretz...

[...]
More importantly: the tip should be in cash, in shekels. Most restaurants will not agree to tack it into the credit card bill.[...]

Read more: http://www.haaretz.com/travel-in-israel/tourist-tip-of-the-day/tourist-tip-211-who-do-you-tip-and-how-much.premium-1.515167